# How to send the values to echo?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
echo "<img src='bloginfo('template_url').'/img/'.$img' />";
```

i want this value bloginfo must be attach to this src of img tag with $img too...
means how can i adjust this  "  and ' to get the result.

Please help  .

Comment: echo `"....".bloginfo('template_url')."....` [PHP manual on basic string handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Go to www.w3schools.com and read for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to

```
echo "<img src='".bloginfo('template_url')."/img/".$img."' />";
```

And always read manual first before asking question.